# Is it possible to build Caffe using MinGW on Windows?

Tags: mingw, caffe

Is it possible to build Caffe using MinGW on Windows?

I'm using this [solution](https://github.com/willyd/caffe-builder) that use cmake, so I assume that cmake can produce solutions/makefile for all types of compilers/build toolchains?

Also I'm not sure what type of options I should use `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"` or `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles"` ?

**Update:**

Seems caffe-builder officially doesn't support MinGW

https://github.com/willyd/caffe-builder/issues/28

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried building Caffe on Windows.

The [git repository](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows?files=1) of Caffe has a `Windows` branch which is led by Microsoft. This branch is being constantly getting frequent updates too.

Comment: But it's also VS oriented `Requirements: Visual Studio 2013` and I need to use MinGW.